# Not typed empty list : Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, option-type

I just tried to write the simplest maybe function I could imagine in Haskell, and got this error message. And magically it only appears, when I try to evaluate myHead for an empty list. What did I do wrong?

```
module Main 
  where

myHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
myHead [] = Nothing
myHead (x:_) = Just x

main = do
print (myHead [])
```

When I run it from a file, I get this output :

```
main.hs:15:1: error:
  • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
    prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
    Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
 These potential instances exist:
   instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
   instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
   instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
    ... plus 22 others
     ...plus 12 instances involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
 • In a stmt of a 'do' block: print (myHead [])
  In the expression: do { print (myHead []) }
  In an equation for ‘main’: main = do { print (myHead []) }
  <interactive>:3:1: error:
   • Variable not in scope: main
   • Perhaps you meant ‘min’ (imported from Prelude)
```

Comment: If you run this in a *shell*, then you define multiple `myHead` functions.

Comment: Your title is misleading. Where does your error say "Non exhaustive patterns?" Please change it accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with `myHead`, you would have the same issue if you used:

```
main = do
   print Nothing
```

The issue here is that `Nothing` and `myHead []` have a polymorphic type `Maybe a`, for any `a`. Then, `print` is called to write that value. For that, `print` has to require that `Maybe a` is convertible to string: it does that by requiring `Show (Maybe a)`, which in turn it requires `Show a`.

However, there is no universal instance of `Show a`: the compiler now needs to know what `a` is before it can convert that to string.

Note this

```
print (Just 3 :: Maybe Int) -- OK
print (Just id :: Maybe (Int->Int)) -- Not OK! Functions can not be printed
```

The solution is to use a concrete type for your code

```
main = do
   print (myHead [] :: Maybe Int) -- or any other showable type
```

Comment: I wonder what the type system would need to be able to recognize that the value of `show Nothing` is independent of the concrete type.

Comment: @chepner That would also require proving that the argument of `print` is indeed `Nothing`, which is unfeasible in general. Still, for the cases where this is feasible, it would be indeed interesting to have such a "partially dependent" type system. If we had subtyping, we could let 'Nothing` to have its own subtype of `Maybe a', and define `Show` on the subtype. (This opens new cans of worms, like overlapping instances, though.)

Comment: I figured it would have something to do with dependent types. I was thinking only of direct uses like `show Nothing`, not `show expressionThatMightReduceToNothing`, so I see that's the big stumbling block: too much (undecidable) work for the type checker.

Comment: @MártonKardos If this answer solved your problem, you should also accept it as such!